# CentOS 7 installing latest GNU global says system-python is needed

Tags: installation, centos, python

I am trying to get the latest GNU global (global-6.5.6-1.fc27.aarch64.rpm) installed on a CentOS 7 machine.  I give the following command:

sudo rpm -Uvh global-6.5.6-1.fc27.aarch64.rpm

and get the following:

Failed dependencies:
    /usr/libexec/system-python is needed by global-6.5.6-1.fc27.aarch64.rpm

I have tried updating to python 3.4, but have seen people talking about this all the way back to 2.x.  Still there is no /usr/libexec/system-python.  Otherwise I have not seen anything online that really points to an answer to my situation.

On a hunch I just made a soft and then a hard link of that name to /usr/bin/python34, but no luck.

Can someone let me know what system-python is?  I don't really see it described online, but it seems to be necessary for this install.  I would be very grateful for any pointers.

Comment: Is there a SPEC file or source RPM available for that RPM?

Comment: CentOS 7 is based on Fedora 18, 19: You cannot install a Fedora 27 package! . The source package is here http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/Everything/source/tree/Packages/g/global-6.5.7-1.fc27.src.rpm ... `global-6.5.7` requires python3-devel to build.

Answer (score 0):

- "[System Python](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/System_Python)" is a concept that Fedora created to ship a smaller Python for cloud/container images (as well as protecting system tools from users overwriting /usr/bin/python).
- While you may occasionally get lucky, don't expect Fedora RPMs to install cleanly on CentOS 7.  It often times won't work at all, and when it does install you end up with a Frankenstein-system that is more difficult to maintain.
- Regarding your original issue, global has been [requested](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1451800) for EPEL 7 and is currently available in the [testing repository](https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/FEDORA-EPEL-2017-8b289e3f0b).  If you have epel-release installed, then you can get global by running `yum --enablerepo epel-testing install global`.